# How can I set express module about router?

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, express, router

directoies

```
/config
  -routes.js
/public
  /views
    -index.pug
    /home
      -home.pug
-app.js
```

app.js

```
const express = require('express'),
      app     = express();

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'public/views')));
app.set('view engine', 'pug');

require(__dirname + '/config/routes.js')(app);

app.listen(port);
```

routes.js

```
module.exports = function (app) {
  const express = require('express'),
        router  = express.Router(),
        dir     = app.get('views');

  app.use('/', router);

  router.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.render('index');
  });

  router.get('/home', (req, res) => {
    res.render('/home/home');
  });
};
```

Browser returned error message when I try access to localhost:port/home

Error: Failed to lookup view "/home/home" in views directory "C:\app\public\views"

next code can access to url.

```
router.get('/home', (req, res) => {
  res.render(dir + '/home/home');
});
```

How can I set my express?
I don't wanna use dir variable, I just wanna /home/home.

Comment: Is there other route inaccessible, or this is the only one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is with following code

```
router.get('/home', (req, res) => {
     res.render(dir + '/home/home');
});
```

You don't have to specify the **dir** inside **res.render();** and the **/** forward slash in the beginning should be removed. Since you already told Expressjs to look for the views files in the **views folder** `app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'public/views')));` Change it to `res.render('home/home');` Now it should work.

Comment: Yes but  this line says where the views files will be present `app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'public/views')));`, So express will look for it in the views folder.

Comment: Thanks for answer. It works. Just change '/home/home' to 'home/home'. I understood about my fault.

Comment: Yes having a forward slash is a different meaning @ofleaf. Cheers